# PromQL count absent in a range vector

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to count absents in a range vector in Prometheus PromQL?

I am looking for the easiest way to generate uptime information based on absent metrics.

Eg.: `count_over_time(absent(metric_name)[1w])` but it throws `Error executing query: parse error at char 56: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.Call instead`

Unfortunately I cannot use rules, because I need to go back in time.

The workaround I use is to count the results of this query
`/api/v1/query_range?query=absent(metric_name)&start=1506672546&end=1507277346&step=60` but it is not a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good way to go about this, I'd suggest working off the `up` metric as you can easily use `avg_over_time` on that.